# Details behind the plotResiduals function

Tags: matlab, statistics

I'm following the tutorial at http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/estimate-regression-model-with-multiplicative-arima-errors.html.  The probability plot of the residuals from the model fitting is a bit different from what information I've been able to find online (mostly P-P and Q-Q info).  Intuitively, it makes sense, but I was wondering if there was a more explicit description of constuction of this plot?  The scaling of the vertical axis suggests that it is really a Q-Q plot labelled with probability values on the vertical axis.  "doc plotResiduals" doesn't really go into the details.

I've posted this question at:
http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/cwgFHsBj8a0
[Details behind the plotResiduals function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364734/details-behind-the-plotresiduals-function)
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153298/details-behind-the-plotresiduals-function